# How to Resolve Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details in android studion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-2.0

I got IDE issue like Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details while i got latest update from android studio.

Now i got updated version as android studio 2.1 My Gradle part is

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Please Help if some one experiencing this issues and guide me to resolve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: did you try build and rebuild?

Comment: do `clean` and `rebuild`.

Comment: yeah i have tried many times as well but no luck.

Comment: do you have .9.png in your project

Comment: share complete logcat...

Comment: please add your complete gradle console log